# Vb.Net Largest sum of number in matrix by different row and column

Tags: vb.net, matrix

how can i get largest sum of value in matrix by different row and column.
As example:-

i have these matrix value

```
2 4 5
3 7 9
8 6 1
```

if i select 2 then i cannot select other value which is in the same row and column, i only can select whether 7,9,6,1. then if 7 is selected, i can only select 1.
here sample of calculation.

```
2+7+4= 13
2+9+6= 17
3+4+1= 8
3+6+5= 14
8+7+5= 20
8+4+9= 21
```

so the largest is 21. can anyone help me please

This is my code

```
Function getrandom() As Byte
    Dim Buffer(0) As Byte
    Dim RNG As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
    RNG.GetBytes(Buffer)
    Return Buffer(0) And 7
End Function



Private Sub btnCreateArr_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateArr.Click

    Dim totalAllNumber As Integer = 0
    Dim numbers(3, 3) As Integer
    Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()

    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("C:\Users\pc\Desktop\matrix.txt")

        For x As Integer = 0 To 3
            For y As Integer = 0 To 3
                numbers(x, y) = getrandom()
                totalAllNumber = totalAllNumber + numbers(x, y)
                'MsgBox(x & ":" & y & " -->" & numbers(x,y) & vbCrLf & totalAllNumber)
                writer.Write(numbers(x, y).ToString + " ")
            Next
            writer.Write(vbCrLf)
        Next


        Dim totLargest = 0
        Dim usedX As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
        Dim usedY As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
        Dim indexLargestX As Integer
        Dim indexLargestY As Integer

        For x As Integer = 0 To 3
            Dim largest = 0

            For y As Integer = 0 To 3

                If largest < numbers(x, y) Then
                    'if index array not empty
                    If usedX.Count <> 0 Then
                        'to check whether index of largest is already used or not
                        If usedX.Contains(x) Then
                            largest = largest
                        ElseIf usedY.Contains(y) Then
                            largest = largest
                        End If
                    Else
                        largest = numbers(x, y)
                        indexLargestX = x
                        indexLargestY = y

                         'to stop
                        'here iwant to store the largest index of x and y so that i can use that to check with next largest value must be not in same index whether x or y,
                        'but look like here the value is not add inside 'usedX' and 'usedY'

                        If y = 3 Then
                            usedX.Add(indexLargestX)
                            usedY.Add(indexLargestY)

                        End If

                    End If

                End If

            Next

            writer.Write(vbCrLf + "Largest number in row")
            writer.Write(vbCrLf + largest.ToString + " ")
            totLargest = totLargest + largest
        Next
        writer.Write(vbCrLf + "total : " + totLargest.ToString + " ")

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of someone expecting to pluck code out of thin air.  How are you going to write code if you don't know what it's supposed to do?  You need to spend some time actually thinking through what the code has to do first.  Once you've done that, then you can try to write code to implement the steps you came up with.  If you have problems at that stage, THAT is when you post a question here.  Pretend that you have to write instructions that a person can follow to perform this task manually.  That takes no programming experience so anyone can do that.

Comment: Show the code of what you've tried. And everything @jmcilhinney said.

Comment: sure i have trying to write the code, i have trying using any method that i know but dont get the logic how it work. Atleast if someone can help give me some idea, i really appreciate so then i can keep trying to come out with my own code

Comment: Sorry @AndrewMortimer , i still new programming and in process of learning. Thats why i need advice from experienced people like both of you

Comment: Sorry @jmcilhinney, i still new programming and in process of learning. Thats why i need advice from experienced people like both of you

Comment: I think you have two ways: 1st using a bidimensional array or 2nd using a datatable.

Comment: Read these, and then give it a try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx

Comment: Also try this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk24xdbe(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: "i still new programming and in process of learning". That's the thing though, you don't need ANY programming experience to work out HOW it should be done, only to implement that how in code. Like I said, anyone could write a set of instructions that explained how to do it manually.  Some would be better than others but anyone could do it.  The programming part comes in when you try to write code to implement those instructions.  The problem is that you haven't bothered with the first part, so you have no idea what the code is supposed to do. Solve the problem first, then write code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney bro, first before u code, what you do first? get the logic right? think first before said something. u talking like experience doesn't define your maturity. That's why i said i need help to give me some idea how this will be work so i can proceed with my own code. Don't just trying to see other mistake instead of trying to help. If you don't want to help, don't try making mess here. still have many people that want to help. chill bro

Comment: I do want to help but you don't want to accept the help I'm providing because it would mean thinking a bit harder than you're willing to. That's your prerogative but you're the one who loses out as a result.